# When you fill a bath, Is it different that you fill it directly or non-directly?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

Yesterday I was taking a shower that this thought occurred to me that when you are filling a bath, flask, etc with water in two different ways in specified time, **Will the amount of water in bath be different?**

I did a experiment myself in 'Crocodile Chemistry' and got these results as seen below:

First level was pouring water from a faucet directly to the bath from a specified height for 10 seconds. The result was that approximately 250 cubic centimeter water was poured into it.
[image: First Level of Experiment]

Second level was pouring water from a faucet to a 'already filled beaker' and filling the bath with overflowed water of the beaker at the same height and the same time. The result was similar to the first level.
[image: Second Level of Experiment]

I saw all these but I'm not sure that if they're completely accurate, So I wanted to ask somebody that has experience in this manner: **Do these experiments show the right results or it's different in the real world?**

Comment: This seems more physics related really but aside from the water droplets that will stick to the side of the beaker in the second option, if the same amount of water passes through the tap, then the same amount of water must end up in the bath (assuming the beaker is perfectly full).

Comment: thanks for reminding me of droplets that stick to the beaker, I didn't think of that but as for your second opinion I must say that there is a time limit in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the beaker is at or below the outlet of the faucet, the two values should be nearly identical.  There are very small effects, like water sticking to the outside of the beaker as it overflows or the surface of the water changing shape constantly (splashing out more at some times and less at others as a result.)  Those are insignificant for practical purposes.

If the top of the beaker is above the outlet of the faucet, that is, the faucet is submerged in the beaker, then there will be a small addition to the height to which the water must be pumped.  It's only centimeters, but the pressure increase and flow decrease is entirely measurable and would have a small but significant and predictable effect over the course of running a bath.